# How to install dlib for python3 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, python, compiling, c++, cmake

I'm following this guide https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/ of installation. I did:

```
 mkdir -p ~/src
 cd ~/src
 tar xf dlib-19.1.0.tar.gz
 cd dlib-19.1.0/python_examples
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ../../tools/python
 cmake --build . --config Release
 sudo cp dlib.so /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
```

It says that at this point I should be able to run `import dlib`, but if I run it from virtualenv gives me

```
ImportError: No module named dlib
```

If I run it outside from virtualenv it gives:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_dlib)
```

What am I doing wrong? How to install dlib for python?

UPD: I've tried same for Python2:

```
sudo cp dlib.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

and it worked for python2. So how to do the same for python3?

Comment: Are you aware that (at least by default) `python` is `python2` on Ubuntu 14.04? Are you trying to `import dlib` from `python` or from `python3`?

Comment: Sure, I tried both python2 and python3, but still no effect

Comment: @wasd You said you are trying to run it from a virtualenv? Then you can just activate the virtualenv and use `pip` to install `dlib`. Or if yo have `dlib` installed globally, you can create a virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option.

Comment: @edwinksl If I try to install dlib with pip it gives 
`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least  version "3.4")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found solution by myself but thanks @edwinksl for his tip.
In order to install `dlib` for python3 it's better to use `pip`:

`pip install dlib`

You will need boost python. To get it:

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

If you have  "Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least version "3.4")" error make sure you have cmake > 2.8 (In my case it is 3.2.2). To install cmake > 2.8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't noticed `cmake` was only at version 2.8 in Ubuntu 14.04.